# When you want to replace someone with someone else in a position

Tags: verbs

Imagine an emperor dies. He had two sons prior to his death. The older son was the emperor's successor. After the emperor's death, the older son succeeds to the throne, but after awhile the queen (their mother and the emperor's wife) notices there is something wrong with the older son. She realizes that successor is too incapable for that position and whereas she has such an influence to unseat the son, she does that and now she wants to replace sons with each other.
How shall I say that? Does the verb "succeed" work in the self-made sentence bellow:

> - The queen succeeded the older son with the younger son.

If my sentence doesn't work properly, then I would appreciate it if someone could help me to know how shall I say the sentence in my question in a natural way.

Comment: You've already presented the "solution" in your own question text. Replace ***succeeded*** with ***replaced*** and you're done.

Comment: I knew it @FumbleFingers. I needed to know if the verb "succeed" takes an object in this way or not. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: The usage *X succeeded Y* always means that X ***came after*** Y. You can't use ***succeed*** as an "active" verb to mean that X ***caused*** Y to succeed. That simply doesn't work with either the sense of Y being successful OR the sense of Y coming after something else.

Comment: Thank you very much @FumbleFingers. Very informative, short and to the point comment. Please make your comments an answer if it is possible. :)

Comment: I'd rather wait and see if someone else can explain *why* transitive "succeed" is different to "replace". Of course, it might be just a case of "that's the way the cookie crumbled" (no particular reason; it's just an accident of linguistic history). But from your point of view (and any future learners seeking help on this one) it would obviously be much better if there *was* an explanation. That would probably help you to remember it, *and* the relevant reason might apply to other usages too, so you might find you learn something more than just ***this** is how we use **this** verb*.

Comment: She demoted the older sun, replacing him with the younger one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [supplant](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/supplant?s=t) would work for you?  It implies taking the place of another, frequently using slightly "shady" means.